# How to blend images in python (without blend method)

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

this is an assignment on my class, so i need to blend to images together with python using interpolation but i am missing something, perhaps you can help me understand what.

Heres my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
image_one=Image.open('capone.pgm')
image_two=Image.open('escobar.pgm')

out=Image.new(image_one.mode, image_two.size)

(l,h)=image_one.size
for j in range(0, h):
    for i in range(0, l):
          out.getpixel((i,j)),(image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) +  image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 )

out.save("testaando.jpg","JPEG")
out.show()
```

0.3 is the alpha i want for the blending
the two original images are sime size and mode

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1):

**getpixel** method of PIL.Image **returns** value of a pixel, but to modify it you need to use **putpixel** method. So instead of

```
out.getpixel((i,j)),(image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) +  image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 )
```

use

```
out.putpixel((i,j), (image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) +  image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 ))
```

Comment: @DouglasHeydt If he answered your question please mark his reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as there currently is not much information.

The Line:

```
out.getpixel((i,j)),(image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) +  image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 )
```

Should be:

```
out[i, j] = (image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) +  Image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 )
```